# Description of key in define-key

Tags: menu-bar

I am failing to understand how

```
[menu-bar mcp-topm daphne-subm entry-sweep]
```

is a key as described by `define-key` for constructing menus.

Comment: Cannot ask such questions it seems,

Comment: Correct. We would prefer if you would read the manual, or even just the docstrings, instead of asking us to regurgitate the information contain to you. The documentation for `define-key` specifically says “KEY is a string or a vector of symbols and characters, representing a sequence of keystrokes and events.” Your question is not very clear, but on the off chance that you don’t know what square brackets mean you might check the chapter of the manual on vectors. You might also have considered doing that when you saw that the docstring mentioned vectors.

Comment: Where can I find a clear explanation that the vector for a menu item is actually a key sequence defining the menu hierarchy for the specific menu item ?

Comment: What else would it be? When you define a key, you have to tell it what key sequence triggers the key definition. That is true whether the key sequence consists of real keyboard keys, mouse events, button events, or menu names.

Comment: Right.  Vector of menu hierarchy events for a menu item in equivalent to key sequence combinations when using the keyboard.